# Timer with Audio release

Tags: python, audio, time, timer

I created a timer with a specific condition, when it runs out, it should release an Audio.

My Input :

```
import time
import playsound
run = raw_input("Start? > ")
mins = 0
# Only run if the user types in "start"
if run == "start":
    # Loop until we reach 2 minutes running
    while mins != 2:
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", mins

        if mins ==2:
            playsound.playsound('C:\Audio.mp3', True)

        time.sleep(60)
        # Increment the minute total
        mins += 1
```

But sadly it doesn't release anything

Comment: Why dont you just sleep for 120 seconds and then play the sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not be easier to use the `time.sleep()` function that you are already using in your script to play the sound after two minutes?

Something like the below:

```
import time
import playsound

time.sleep(120)

playsound.playsound("C:\Audio.mp3", True)
```